# suggestion to run Macros with a large number of html files

Tags: html, macros

I have hundred of pages in a server. Html pages for sure, want to execute some Macros to find and replace all the headers, includes with another block of code.

What do you suggest? i have read some people recommends python.

I can run the script in localhost with php or python.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use find and replace(-all) in your HTML editor.

Comment: Its tru you can execute what kind of macros with a simple Find and Replace, but is it the only solution?

Comment: Seems like the simplest option to me. What more do you need?

Comment: I need to use dom recognizer cause block of HTML are not the sames.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Perl. [Search and replace across many files with a perl one-liner](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/298).

```
perl -pi -e 's/about news\.$/about selling advertising space\./' file*
```

Comment: I like it. Its useful, but if i can use a DOM recognizer for html block? its better using python or php, not?

Comment: If the text you are looking for is always the same, there's no need to get into the DOM. It's just a text replace. Should run faster and is less likely to eat itself.